# Unable to get the pdf on jquery ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdf

I am using the [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/?lang=en) to generate the pdf file. I am able to get the pdf file on using the through hyperlink. But unable to get on button click.

Here is code.

**createReport.php**

```
<?php
//$operation = $_POST['action'];
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 16);
$pdf->Cell(40, 10, 'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output('t','D');
?>
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo Report</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#showreport').click(function() {
                $.post("createReport.php", {suggest: "txt"}, function(result) {
                    alert("got it");
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="showreport" value="Show Report"/>
    <a href="createReport.php">click me</a>
</body>
</html>
```

on clicking on click me link i am able to see the report as **hello World**. But on button click nothing is happening. I need to send the data like from and to date and i want to generate report from db.

Kindly suggest me  where i am going wrong .

Appreciate your response.

Thank you.

Comment: If you need to pass in the from and to date, you'd put those variables into your data object in your AJAX request. I don't see the fields for that data anywhere in your code so won't be able to help any further..

Comment: No that is my requirement. but for testing purpose i am just sending some data. If i can succeed in sending "suggest" param. i can proceed further.

Comment: OK, firstly if you're getting a report, you should be using GET not POST. Second, have you checked your console for errors, tracked the AJAX request, done any sort of debugging at all? I can simply presume that you aren't getting your alert as expected, which would point to a failed request, which could be because of many reasons including wrong URL, Javascript syntax error, PHP syntax errors, anything!!

Comment: i used post only. and i am getting the alert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace

```
alert("got it");
```

with below code

```
var uri = 'data:application/pdf;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(data);                              window.open(uri, 'tiketi.pdf');
```